# Is there any way to resolve issue in which two simultaneous call to two different classes waiting for each other

Tags: c#, multithreading, deadlock, contextswitchdeadlock

I have two different classes in my project which are responsible for some opening and execution of modules and are called from some other solution. My solution doesn't support multi threading.

Now my problem is --
I have one class **CPMModule.cs**

```
    public bool QueryLinkActivate()
            {               
                while (true)
                {               
                    if (!_cpmBridge.isBlocked() && !_cpmBridge.isClosing())
                    {                   
                        return true;
                    }               
                }
            }
```

This method is called to check when module window is ready to handle new call by check `_cpmBridge.isBlocked()` and `_cpmBridge.isClosing()` values, and when it returns true a new module is opened.

I have another method in another class **CallListenerClass.cs** -

```
    public void stopModal()
            {
                _cpmModule.StopModal();
            }
```

This method is responsible to close any pop up window opened in the screen and its associated execution.

Now my problem is like -- A pop up window is opened in my screen and when I close this pop up window the this `stopModal()` method execution starts, and some times a new call for `QueryLinkActivate()` method comes.

Here in this case `stopModal()` execution doesn't get completed and the execution is switched to another  method i.e `QueryLinkActivate()` in which there is a loop which keeps checking that module is free or not for which `stopModal()` execution needs to get completed which never gets completed due to `QueryLinkActivate()` while loop. And my application goes in Not responding state which then only can be closed by Task manager.

Can some help how can I handle this situation? How can i complete `stopModal()` execution and then resume `QueryLinkActivate()` method execution.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your `while` loop is very tight. Can you afford to introduce `sleep` between each iteration? But most importantly it will be interesting to know how those 2 functions are called simultaneously.

Comment: Hi Athanasios, Thanks,

Comment: You have a potentially infinite loop there. A non-responsive program is exactly what I would expect to happen.

Comment: Hi Theodor, This loop keps on checking until the loop returns true, here in this situation you are right, it keeps running infinite time.